# How to build for release in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: release, archive, xcode4.3

I haven't used Xcode since version 3.x. Now I have 4.3 and I can't figure out how to build for release and then get my app to the app store. (This is an update to an existing app). According to Apple documentation, you have to Archive your app first. Their instructions say:

1. From the Scheme toolbar menu, choose a scheme.
2. From the same menu, choose Edit Scheme to display the scheme dialog.

Problem is, I don't see any "Scheme toolbar menu" or "Edit Scheme" button, so I can't get passed that step.

Answer (score 0):

An Xcode scheme defines a collection of targets to build, a configuration to use when building, and a collection of tests to execute.

You can have as many schemes as you want, but only one can be active at a time. You can specify whether a scheme should be stored in a project—in which case it’s available in every workspace that includes that project, or in the workspace—in which case it’s available only in that workspace. When you select an active scheme, you also select a run destination (that is, the architecture of the hardware for which the products are built).

The link below shows how to manage the sceme
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeManage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH8

Comment: Well, I found the "Edit Scheme" (which is in the Product menu btw), and I created an Archive successfully. But the archive does NOT show up in the Organizer, so I still can't proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I got the Archive to show up in the Organizer. I had to go into the build settings and, under deployment, change Skip Install from Yes to No for the Release version.